# generator-jhipster separate client (Front) with server (Back)

Tags: jhipster

I work on a project with jhipster where I 'm supposed to separate my back and my front. I do that by typing the command yo jhipster:client and yo jhipster:server but the performance I get the following error:

```
Your request can not be processed. Sorry, an error occurred. 
Status: Not Found (Not Found)
Message: No message available
Other suggestions: Search localhost: 9000
```

I wonder if I should actually separate the two parts of my project into different folder or just put them in the same folder as for a while.

Thank you

Comment: Can you translate the error? Don't expect people to understand french on an english community website...

Comment: So, the following error is:
Your request can not be processed Sorry, an error occurred. Status: Not Found (Not Found) Message: No message available Other suggestions : Search localhost: 9000: